# Unexpected token ILLEGAL from multi line string via template toolkit

Tags: javascript, template-toolkit

I have a js script in a html page that is preprocessed by template::toolkit.

The script is as follows;

```
<script>
    $(function(){ 
    var floot = {
        id : [% floot.id %],
        image : '[% floot.image %]',
        title : "[% floot.title %]",
        desc : "[% floot.desc %]",
        history : []
    };
            /* unrelated stuff */
            /* set click event to display the floot details in an overlay */
    $('#' + floot.id).children('.openDetails').click(function() { 
        bubbleDetails(floot, user);
    });
</script>
```

the problem is that floot.desc can contain line breaks - it's a description, and I'd like to preserve them, however js barfs chips on the line breaks giving the Unexpected token error.

I've tried a number of TT filters for example

```
[% floot.desc | html_line_break | replace('\n', ' ') %]
```

This successfully removes the line breaks and replaces them with <\br> (excuse the backslash, the editor is interpreting the br s otherwise) however it doesn't work, the page is then rendered with <\br> in it rather than a break.

At this stage I'm thinking that the only way to do this is search for <\br> in floot.desc from within bubbleDetails and replace any occurrences of it with newlines, however I wanted to check if anyone knew of a better, less clunky way to do it?

thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this package before, but looking at the docs this one looks like it might be what you need:

http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html

scroll down to dquote section

escapes double quotes also, which would probably be good

Comment: Hi Thanks for the input.  With dquote I get the same problem.  The newline is transformed but then, when I display floot.desc later, it now displays the transformed text, not the original.

Comment: if the js desc string looks ok, then the problem must be within `bubbleDetails`. if you view source is it showing `\n` or `\\n`? If it's just `\n` then bubbleDetails is probably doing some encoding

Answer (score 0):

There are TT plugins for handling JSON conversion, which is what you are effectively if not explicitly doing. Code generation should be avoided if at all possible - let the plugin worry about such arcane issues.

I like JSON::Escape, which you could execute like this:

```
[% USE JSON::Escape; %]
<script>
    $(function(){ 
    var floot = [% floot.json %];
    floot.history = []; // might not even be necessary?
    };
            /* unrelated stuff */
            /* set click event to display the floot details in an overlay */
    $('#' + floot.id).children('.openDetails').click(function() { 
        bubbleDetails(floot, user);
    });
</script>
```

[This related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13578228/14750) may be useful also.

If you go this way and the error still occurs, then as @agreco says, it must be an issue in the `bubbleDetails()` function.